# Spark multiple count distinct in single expression

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a following code written in Spark using Scala and SQL API:

```
sourceData
  .groupBy($"number")
  .agg(                        
       countDistinct(when(...something...)),
       countDistinct(when(...something...)),
       countDistinct(when(...something...)),
       countDistinct(when(...something...))),
       countDistinct(when(...something...)))
```

When I check execution plan, Spark internally does something called "expand" and it multiples records 5 times(for each count distinct column). As I already have billions of records, this becomes very inefficient to do. Is there a way to do this in more efficient way, and please do not say countApproxDistinct as I need exact values :)

Comment: I won't say `countApproxDistinct` but I'll say your out of luck. You could try `size(collect_set(...))`, but keep in mind, that `count_distinct` schedules separate scans, to avoid runtime errors.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to engineer new columns (1 or 0) before the aggregations and then just do a max().  This should reduce the number of scans.

```
sourceData
  .withColumn("engineered_col1", expr("CASE WHEN ... THEN 1 ELSE 0 END")
  .withColumn("engineered_col2", expr("CASE WHEN ... THEN 1 ELSE 0 END")
  .groupBy($"number")
  .agg(max($"engineered_col1"),max($"engineered_col2"))
```